# How to correctly install pyinstaller

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I have attempted to install pyinstaller (on Ubuntu 16.0.4) using pip:

```
pip3 install pyinstaller

Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.2.tar.gz
Collecting setuptools (from pyinstaller)
  Using cached setuptools-25.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: pyinstaller
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyinstaller ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/.../.cache/pip/wheels/fc/b3/10/006225b1c1baa34750a7b587d3598d47d18114c06b696a8e0e
Successfully built pyinstaller
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pyinstaller
Successfully installed pyinstaller setuptools-20.7.0
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

However, if I then try to call `pyinstaller` I get the error `pyinstaller: command not found`

Why am I unable to run pyinstaller when the pip install appears to have been successful.

Comment: You need to make sure you've got the executable on your path

Comment: What happens if you run `which pyinstaller`?

Comment: Nothing is found with `which pyinstaller`

Comment: It looks like you need to [build a bootloader](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bootloader-building.html#building-the-bootloader)

Comment: You can also try to call via module: `python -m PyInstaller [...]`

Answer (score 14):

`pyinstaller` appears to have installed correctly, but the command is not available on `PATH`. You need to locate where the executable was placed. This will depend on your system configuration, if you're using virtualenv, and other system and usage dependent factors.

One thing you could try is using `find` to locate the executable:

```
sudo find / -name pyinstaller
```

This recursively looks for a file named `pyinstaller`, starting at the root of the file system. If you have some idea where the executable may have been placed, you can narrow the search to that directory.

Once you have the absolute path of the executable, you can either call it directly:

```
/my/path/to/pyinstaller
```

Or if you're not using virtualenv or anything, you could modify `PATH` to include the executable's parent directory:

```
$PATH = $PATH:/my/path/to
```

If you want to make that change permanent, you need to [modify a script somewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117467/84908).

Comment: In ubuntu pyinstaller will be located in `~/.local/bin/pyinstaller`